# How can I add a new mode in xv6?

Tags: system, xv6

The exec mode of a processor is divided into two mode, which are user mode and administrator mode, and how can I add a new mode called administrator mode? When a process is forked, it will start from user mode, and by adding a system call, it will be on administrator mode.

Comment: You can add some boolean into `struct proc` (proc.h) but what is you final need? What can't you do today in priviligied mode?

Comment: "administrator" mode (in Windows) is similar to the concept of "sudo" in Unix. This "super" mode is meaningful only if the OS has a concept of read/write/execute permission for files. xv6 does not implement file permissions. (Kernel vs user mode is a separate concept).